# Position cursor at end of variable or array member

Tags: vim

Consider the way of representing variables and array members in PHP:

```
$something
$something['member']
```

How might I ensure that the cursor is on the last character? Simply using `E` will not help as the variable might be followed by other characters, as so:

```
echo "I saw (".$something.") happen.";
echo "I saw (".$something['member'].") happen.";
```

I would prefer an answer that would let the cursor be anywhere on the relevant text (`$something` or `$something['member']`) but I would be satisfied with an answer that works at least on the characters `something`.

Note that my goal is to use the answer of this question to precede the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>fv a}<Esc>ldf"F$i{<Esc>dF"
```

That mapping is meant to turn this:

```
echo "I saw (".$something.") happen.";
echo "I saw (".$something['member'].") happen.";

echo "I saw (" . $something . ") happen.";
echo "I saw (" . $something['member'] . ") happen.";
```

Into this:

```
echo "I saw ({$something}) happen.";
echo "I saw ({$something['member']}) happen.";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this differently. While you really want "a variable" what you're loosely asking for which should be close enough is "everything inside the quotes, plus also the quotes themselves". For this you can use the `a"` text-object (`:help text-objects`). Place the cursor anywhere on the relevant text, type `va"` to visually select the area you want, or press `"ada"` to delete the relevant text and place it in the 'a' register, or do whatever else you want with the text object. It should be fairly simple (maybe using `substitute()`, maybe using a different method) to massage the text to be what you want.

This is also a case I'd normally use a recorded macro, to tell the truth.

If `a"` selects too much, you can try the patch to add arbitrary text objects, so that you can use `im.` (inside-matching-. character) to get everything from '.' to the other '.', or similar. Get the patch here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/pZxLAAXxk0M/discussion (note there are multiple patches, you probably want the last one).

Comment: Thank you Ben. I don't want everything inside the quotes, but rather I want (firstly) to replace the leading `"` (inclusive) up until the `$` (exclusive) with the `{` character, and then (secondly) I want to replace everything from the last character of the variable (exclusive) up until the next `"` character (inclusive) with the `}` character.

Comment: Yes, but all that stuff is inside the quotes. So you could (for example) map it to: `@ada":let @a=substitute(@a, '.*\$', '$', '')<CR>"ap` to get rid of the first quote and everything up to the $. (untested)